# Где нужно указать Client ID, который получаешь в консоли разработчика?

Tags: java, android, google-api

Я зарегистрировал Google-аккаунт для `Google LogIn` и, следуя инструкции туториала, выполнил всё, и вот в конце я получаю `Client ID` как на скриншоте показано:

[image: Скриншот получения ID]

И написано, что это ID для Android-приложения, но дальше в туториале нигде не упоминается о том, где его нужно использовать...

Нужно ли его как-то указывать в приложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам вручную его указывать нигде не надо, но надо скачать Json (кнопочка снизу) и поместить его в корень проекта (или модуль app, не помню точно). Это должен быть файл `google-services.json` из коего приложение и будет брать все эти значения самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

**Google** использует `OAUTH 2.0` для авторизации своих пользователей в сторонних приложениях. Собственно `client_id` это часть спецификации указанного протокола. Более подробно ты можешь почитать на той же [странице Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). Что касательно того, где указать данный параметр, то это уже вопрос твоего инструмента, который реализует данный протокол. Но вопросы подобного рода уже относятся не к **Google**, а к протоколу `OAUTH 2.0`.